# SilverStripe restrict level-3 child pages

Tags: php, silverstripe

What is the easiest and most convenient way to restrict CMS users from creating level-3 child pages?

I've tried this in `class Page`

```
public function canHaveChild() {

    //Get SiteTree column value ParentID of this record
    $parentID = DataObject::get("SiteTree", "WHERE ID = '$this->ID'")->ParentID;

    //If parentID = 0, this is a root page, so it can have a childpage
    if($parentID == 0) {
        $this->allowed_children = array("Page", "BasicPage", "FormPage");
    } else {
        $this->allowed_children = false;
    }

}
```

With this function, I can still create child pages far down the tree, so it doesn't change allowed_children

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override SilverStripe's `allowedChildren` function.

```
class Page extends SiteTree
{
    public function allowedChildren()
    {
        if($this->Level(3))
            return [];

        return ['Page', 'BasicPage', 'FormPage'];
    }
}
```

With this you don't need to set the `$allowed_children` property.

Comment: Works perfectly using `$this->Level(2)`